# WPF Storyboard GetCurrentState

Tags: wpf, state, storyboard

I am trying to detect when a storyboard is still active, still has an effect on a property(ie completed by still has a hold on the dependecy property it is animating).

Completed="DeviceExplorer_Completed"> 
      
Duration="0:0:0.5">

In code I do
     Storyboard aStoryBoard = this.Resources["openDeviceExplorer"] as Storyboard;
     aStoryBoard.Begin();

But how do I find out if the animation is still active, or still has an effect on the property value?

I tried
            ClockState aClockState = ClockState.Stopped;
            aClockState = aStoryBoard.GetCurrentState();

and keep getting the InvalidOperationException "Cannot perform action because the specified Storybopard was not applied to this object ofr interactive control"

I tried a number of permutations like 
aStoryBoard.Begin(this, true);
aStoryBoard.Begin(aPanelExternalAvailableCamerasControl, true);

and still keep getting this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the Storyboard is controllable. From MSDN: "To make a storyboard controllable in code, you must use the appropriate overload of the storyboard's Begin  method and specify true to make it controllable."

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc672521.aspx